# Aggregate Sum in Django. Sum of objects with the same name

Tags: python, django, sum, aggregate

I have the following **QuerySet**, this is a shopping list:

```
<QuerySet
    [
    <Cart_object: {name: 'Apple', amount: 10}, {name: 'Bananas', amount: 20},
    <Cart_object: {name: 'Bananas', amount: 10}>
    ]
>
```

I apply the following code to it, and I get the sum of all products for each of the objects:

```
for obj in cart:
    from_cart = UserProduct.objects.filter(obj=obj).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
    print(from_cart)
```

**Out**:

```
{'amount__sum': 30}
{'amount__sum': 10}
```

The question is as follows. How to use aggregate (Sum ('amount')) to add only those objects that have the same 'name'. To get one Cart_object, in which **'Apple' = 10**, and **'Bananas' = 30** (Since there are records with the same name)

```
<Cart_object: {name: 'Apple', amount: 10}, {name: 'Bananas', amount: 30}>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried the GROUP BY expression?

```
UserProduct.objects.values("obj").annotate(sum=Sum('amount')).order_by("obj")
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL command for this, is `SELECT "userproduct"."name", SUM("userproduct"."amount") AS "the_amount" FROM "table" GROUP BY "userproduct"."name"`.

What you can have with Django by doing:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
UserProduct.objects.values('name').annotate(the_amount=Sum('amount'))
```